# How to perform actions on tables row in JQuery mobile

Tags: jquery-mobile, ibm-mobilefirst

I have a table which displays results like the image posted below. Now I need to do some actions on each row by selecting it. There are two options I can think of,

[image]

1) We can provide a radio button for each row & a drop down on the right side to perform an action. But here i need to generate this code dynamically from a javascript file like below

```
      function getMessage(result){



for (var j = 0; j < result.invocationResult.resultSet.length; j++) {
    var tmp = "<tr>";
    var resSet = result.invocationResult.resultSet[j];

    for(res in resSet){
        tmp += "<td>" + resSet[res] + "</td>";

    }

    $("#mytable > tbody").append(tmp+"</tr>");

    $('#AppBody').hide();
    $('#AuthBody').hide();
    $('#ResTable').show(); 

}

      }
```

2) Provide a link to a particular item in the row like Dispute Number & when clicked it should take me to another page where I can perform those action with a drop down. But here the links should be applied dynamically to the items in the rows. As per my knowledge we should not navigate using href as i am using worklight.

Please help me with approach and also examples.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I'm not sure what is the issue you are facing with option 1...

As for option 2,
There is no problem navigating to another "page" using Worklight and jQuery Mobile, as long as you're doing it responsibly (definitely **not** use `href`). That is, not lose the Worklight context, at which point stuff will stop working.

The idea is this:
In the app's index.html you (will/should) have a `<div data-role="page">` and in the case of Worklight, you will need to switch its contents with another from some other HTML file.

Here's a simplified Worklight 6.2 sample project: https://github.com/IdanAdar/Multipage-Navigation-Using-jQM

In the HTML:

```
<a href="#" data-role="button" id="button-mainpage" onclick="changeToSomePage();">load page1</a>
```

In the JavaScript:

```
function changeToSomePage() {
    $(':mobile-pagecontainer').pagecontainer('change','somepage.html');
}
```

Comment: I need to generate link for a particular item for all the rows in the javascript function getMessage() (while populating the table). And also, I have to make sure changeToSomePage() javascript method gets called when the user clicks on any link ?

Now, when the user clicks on a particular link, changeToSomePage() should be called and I should somehow retrieve the item number , so that I can display the details of that particular item by querying the database in another page ? 
Can you please help me on how can I retrieve the item number in the changeToSomePage() function ?